# Reacharts: I need help getting data from json object

Tags: reactjs, recharts

[image: jSON data]

I am using React Recharts for my visualization, however, I am having a challenge displaying a line chart with different corresponding object contents. I have `JSON` object, I would like to have the months of subcriptions as my XAxis and total of annual_payment moves as my YAxs. Ideally, the image below is representation of how I want to display my data. Instead of week, I need to display months. Thank you
[image: LineChart]

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: class mainpage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        subscriptions: [],
        data: [],
        selectedSubscriptionId: null,
        detailmode: false,
        totalYearlyPayment: 0,
        totalMonthlyPayment: 0,
        category: null

    };
}

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, at first you have to manipulate your `subscriptions` array:
lets say you want to show month of `date_purchased` in your XAxis. So you can do:

```
subscriptions_manipulated = subscriptions.map(el => {
  el.date_purchased = new Date(el.date_purchased).getMonth() + 1 // + 1 because for January getMonth returns 0...
  return el;
});
```

Then you can make your graph:

```
<LineChart data={subscriptions_manipulated}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
       <XAxis dataKey="date_purchased" interval="preserveStartEnd" />
       <YAxis />
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line name="annual_payment" type='monotone' dataKey='annual_payment' />
</LineChart>
```